# Java - how many times is the breakpoint hit?

Tags: java, breakpoints

i was wondering how many times the breakpoint is hit.

The question asks: for each of the first 4 hits, write down the values of currentMin, current Max and mid that can be seen in the debugger.

the values i have are: n=40, currentMin=0, currentMax=40 and mid=20.

is this four hits? or would i need to go round the cycle four times using the above values?

```
public class Breakpoint {

        public int breakp() {

                int n = 40;

                int currentMin = 0;
                int currentMax = n;

                while (currentMin < currentMax) {
                        int mid = (currentMin + currentMax) / 2;
                        if (mid * mid + mid + 1 <= n)//breakpoint is on this line {
                                currentMin = mid;
                        } else {
                                currentMax = mid;
                        }
                }
                return currentMin;

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                Breakpoint b = new Breakpoint();
                int a = b.breakp();
                System.out.println(a);
        }

}
```

Comment: I think this is a little confusing because the class is also named "Breakpoint".  I'm assuming the problem points to a breakpoint somewhere in your while loop?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that the breakpoint is put on line 5 and n has the value 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the breakpoint is post this line:

```
if (mid * mid + mid + 1 <= n){
```

After 4 iteration the values should read..

```
n:40 mid:7 currentMin:5 currentMax:10
```

Comment: thanks, i forgot to add which line the breakpoint was on. but using your example, i get the general gist

Answer (score 1):

The first four hits that I received while tracing through the program are:

```
min=0, max=40, mid=20

min=0, max=20, mid=10

min=0, max=10, mid=5

min=5, max=10, mid=7
```

You would need to go around the function four times to acquire these values.